# Rails 5 Failing Test ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord

I'm currently working through *Agile Development with Rails 5* and have run into an issue with my testing. Namely, there is an association mismatch going on where it expects the Product but gets a String. I've tried fixing the line in my line_items_controller_test.rb from @line_item.product to @line_item.product_id to no avail and have poked around as much as I know how.

Here is my test file line_items_controller_test.rb

```
  test "should update line_item" do
    patch line_item_url(@line_item), params: { line_item: { cart_id: @line_item.cart_id, product: @line_item.product } }
    assert_redirected_to line_item_url(@line_item)
  end
```

and my test failure from the terminal

```
Error:
LineItemsControllerTest#test_should_update_line_item:
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Product(#70143083725900) expected, got String(#70143078473840)
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:47:in `block in update'
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:46:in `update'
    test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:40:in `block in <class:LineItemsControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:39
```

and here is the controller itself where it mentions 47 and 46 beginning with respond_to

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Let me know if there's any more info you need. You can also check my repo at https://github.com/jamesemcc/depot

Comment: Can you post the `line_item_params` method?

Comment: Are you able to update the line item in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. There are problems not only in your test, but in app.

1. https://github.com/jamesemcc/depot/blob/master/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb#L75 You should permit `product_id`, not `product` here. You cannot pass `Product` object from browser.
2. You should pass `product_id` from view and from test

Good Luck!

Comment: Awesome, thanks unkmas! I think it stemmed from accidentally writing `product:reference` instead of `product:references` when I generated the LineItem.